# How to abort thread in multithreading after some defined specific time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Thread thr1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
Thread thr2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));
Thread thr3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread3));
Thread thr4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread4));
Thread thr5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread5));

thr1.Start();
thr2.Start();
thr3.Start();
thr4.Start();
thr5.Start();
```

I want to just stop each thread after 1000 miliseconds.

Comment: So make sure that whatever each ThreadX is running, that it completes within 1000ms. Don't abort threads. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread doesn't work that way. Here is a list of what you can do:

- Give a thread small amount of work, so it completes in ~ 1 second (this is not the best option though)
- Use `volatile bool` or  classes derived from `WaitHandle` to cancel work in a thread
- Use classes that support cancelation: `Task` or `BackgroundWorker`

In any case, do not call `thread.Abort` as it may leave your application in an unstable state.

Comment: i want to stop these five threads after execution of four minutes are done.

Comment: @user3567592 then option 2 and 3 are good for your. You can use a timer that will tick in four minutes. On timer elapsed event you can "cancel" the work thread.

Comment: thank you very much. now i have use BackgroundWorker.